# Finding Surface Area of A Right Cone with Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm really struggling with this question and I think a lot of it has to do with the visualization of it (I've drawn pictures but for some reason I'm still having trouble).

Work:
Let R be the radius of the cone and H be the height of the cone.

I am trying to find it using cylindrical coordinates so to find an expression for the SA from the sides: The intercept of my cone is at the origin so I have $z=mr+b$ where $b=0$ and $m=\frac{H}{R}$, from this I obtain $z=r \frac{H}{R}\Rightarrow r=z\frac{R}{H}$ which will be integrated from $0\to R$, theta will just be going from $0\to 2\pi$, and finally for the z axis integral I have from similar triangles if S is the hypotenus: $ds=\frac{S}{H}dh$

From this I obtain $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{H} (\frac{S}{H}dh)(z\frac{R}{H}dr)(d\theta)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{H}S\frac{R}{H^2}z\cdot dhdrd\theta$=$\pi SR^2$

Surface area from the top of the cone: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}rdrd\theta=\pi R^2$

Total SA then is: $SA=\pi SR^2+\pi R^2$ which is incorrect since it should be $SA=\pi SR+\pi R^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see even before you’ve evaluated the integral that something’s not right by doing some dimensional analysis: it’s got a dimension of length$^3$, which isn’t going to give you an area. The mistake lies in integrating both with respect to $r$ and $h$. You’ve established that $r$ is a function of $h$, so letting $h$ vary from $0$ to $H$ also takes care of the variation in $r$. By also integrating with respect to $r$, you’re “filling in” the cone.

This is a fairly simple instance of a surface of revolution. Since $h=z$, let’s eliminate an extraneous variable by dropping the former. The surface area element is $dA = r\,d\theta\,ds$. Substituting your values, $$dA = \left(\frac R H z\right)d\theta\frac S H dz = \frac{RS}{H^2}z\,d\theta\,dz.$$ This is more promising: it has a dimension of length$^2$. Integrating, we get $$
A = \frac{RS}{H^2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^Hr\,dr = \frac{RS}{H^2}\cdot2\pi\cdot\frac{H^2}2 = \pi RS,
$$ as expected.

Another way to see why you shouldn’t integrate with respect to both $r$ and $z$ is to slice the cone up into narrow circular bands. This corresponds to computing the area as $A=\int_0^H\cdots dz$. Each of these bands has height and covers an angle of $2\pi$, but the band’s radius is essentially fixed. There’s no “inside” to the band for $r$ to range over.